# Wildfly 10 issue with css file

Tags: jsf, directory, jsf-2.2, outputstylesheet

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="test/css"  name="style.css" />
```

Above code is not working in `wildfly 10` with jar file `jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2`.

Issue getting is:

```
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, style.css, from library, test/css.
```

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Try using google first.... And you are saying it works in wildfly 8 or 9? Or in 10 with a different jsf impl?

Comment: Its working in 8. But not working in 9 and 10

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used ... and pay attention to the 'library' and 'name' parts

Comment: The `library` attribute doesn't represent a folder/path. It represents a library name (e.g. `primefaces`, `omnifaces`, `javax.faces`, etc). If you have none, get rid of it and just use `name="test/css/style.css"`.

Comment: It is not a WildFly 10 issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of a library attribute should not be a path but a reference to a single folder (grouping css ,js etc.) and a direct descendant of the resources folder.

So changing

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="test/css"  name="style.css" />
```

to

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="test"  name="css/style.css" />
```

should make it work.

Mojarra has been too liberal in this and it seems they are 'improving' things. I ran into a similar difference with the location of composite components. MyFaces did not allow paths in there as well, while Mojarra (until at least 2.2.12) still does.

For more details on best usage, see

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: I created this answer but still marked is as a duplicate of the 'see also'